# Combining data from multiple arrays into a final array for output in CSV

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to restructure my arrays so that I can get the desired output in one final array that will be used to fill a csv, eventually spreadsheet.

My first msyql query and the resulting array give me this structure:

```
array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku_id] => 1
            [dealer_id] => 1976
            [locations] => 1
            [groupID] => 1
            [frame] => 1051
            [cover] => 1150
            [color] => 99
            [start_date] => 2018-03-
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku_id] => 1
            [dealer_id] => 5400
            [locations] => 1
            [groupID] => 1
            [frame] => 1051
            [cover] => 1150
            [color] => 99
            [start_date] => 2017-04-
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sku_id] => 1
            [dealer_id] => 11316
            [locations] => 1
            [groupID] => 1
            [frame] => 1051
            [cover] => 1150
            [color] => 99
            [start_date] => 2017-02-
        )
 )
```

So I get 3 records, each for the same product (sku_id) but a different customer(dealer_id). Then I match this data up in a similar table in DB2 to get quantity for each order of the sku_id. That 2nd query/array shows this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CSTNOC] => 1976
            [TOTALQTY] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CSTNOC] => 5400
            [TOTALQTY] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CSTNOC] => 11316
            [TOTALQTY] => 14
        )

)
```

However, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

In the below example, sku_id, groupID and location would come directly from the first query. Days is the number of days between start_date (from query 1) and curDate(). Qty is orqtyc from query 2 and Average is a calculation based on locations, days and qty. Each row is based on a different customer, so even though the below example is for one sku, the rows signify a different customer with different locations, qty, etc.

```
SKU_id    |   groupID   | locations (n) | Days (x) | Qty(q) | Average (x/(q/n))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123              1            3             120         15           24
123              1            2             12          6            4
```

The Report or CSV would then only show one line item for the above:

```
SKU   |   Group   |   Average Days   |   Total units sold
123   |     1     |        28        |          21
```

Basically, for every sku I'm getting those records and then I need  to do those calculations by row, and get a total of those values for each sku. The report will only have one line item per sku.

I have everything I need to get there, but how can I structure a final array to get my desired outputs like above?

FULL SCRIPT:

```
    $skuQuery = "
    SELECT 
        sku_id,
        dealer_id,
        locations,
        s.sku_group_id as groupID,
        s.frame as frame,
        s.cover1 as cover,
        s.color1 as color,
        start_date - interval 7 day as start_date
    from products p
    inner join skus s on p.sku_id = s.id
    where curdate() between p.start_date and p.expire_date
    group by sku_id, dealer_id
    limit 3";

$skuRslt = mysqli_query($conn,$skuQuery);

while($skuRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($skuRslt)){

    $skuResult[] = $skuRow;

    $dealerQuery = "
        SELECT
              cstnoc,
              sum(orqtyc) as TotalQTY
          from table
            where cstnoc = {$skuRow['dealer_id']}
            AND framec = {$skuRow['frame']}
              AND colr1c = {$skuRow['color']}
              AND covr1c =  {$skuRow['cover']}
              AND extd2d >= " . str_replace('-', '', $skuRow['start_date']) . "
        group by cstnoc, framec
    ";

    $dealerRslt = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $dealerQuery);

    foreach($skuResult as $skuRow){
        while($dealerRow = odbc_fetch_array($dealerRslt)){

                $dealerResult[] = $dealerRow;
        }
    }
    print_r($dealerResult);
}
```

Comment: What ties these together it can't be all those fields, it would be much easier with 1 query,  If your associating these based on 5 fields that's well gonna cause a lot of pain.  That's what PK id's are for

Comment: One query is in mysql and one is in db2. Unfortunately, I have to use frame, cover and color in order to relate the sku_id from mysql to the same product in db2 (frame/cover/color combo makes it unique). So the mysql query has the sku_id, locations and start_date that I need, but the db2 query has the quantity that I need per order